# unselectedLabelstyle don't work in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar

Why my `unselectedLabelStyle` does not work to me?
after save my changes with textStyle attribute in this unselectedLabelStyle nothing will change to me :/

```
class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;

  PageController pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        children: <Widget>[
          HomeScreen(),
          MapScreen(),
          SearchScreen(),
          AccountScreen(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black, size: 32),
        // selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 26, color: Colors.grey.shade300),
        unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade300),//HEEEEEERRRRRRRRREEEEEE
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedPage = index;
          });

          pageController.animateToPage(
            index,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve:
                Curves.easeInOutExpo, 
          );
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
              ),
              title: Text('Główna', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.location_on,
              ),
              title: Text('Mapa', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
              ),
              title: Text('Szukaj', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
            ),
            title: Text('Konto', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overlapping textStyle by providing title style directly in title, moreover you can use **unselectedItemColor** property to change colour of unelected items.

```
unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
```

Change title from

```
 title: Text('Główna', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
```

To:

```
 title: Text('Główna')),
```

Moreover, i think you should file bug in flutter sdk becuase it is not working as expected as you mention.

```
 /// If [selectedLabelStyle.color] and [unselectedLabelStyle.color] values
  /// are non-null, they will be used instead of [selectedItemColor] and
  /// [unselectedItemColor].
```

As per the following documentation comment if you specify color of unselectedLabelStyle then it should use that color but it is not using it.

Answer (score 3):

`title` is deprecated for `BottomNavigationBar`, use `label` instead and use these properties to style the label and icon.

```
        BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppColors.primary),
            unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppColors.primary),
            selectedFontSize: 12,
            unselectedFontSize: 12,
            selectedItemColor: AppColors.caption,
            unselectedItemColor: AppColors.caption,
```

Comment: thanks man, I was using selectedLabelStyle property, but apparently it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use below simple solution to change the **selectedLabelStyle** and **unselectedLabelStyle** - (color for label text ):

```
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: appWhiteColor,
        elevation: 1,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/race_icon_fill.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/race_icon.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: 'My Races',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/horse_icon_fill.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/horse_icon.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: 'My Horses',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/remainder_icon_fill.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              color: Colors.amber,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/remainder_icon.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              color: Colors.grey,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            label: 'My Reminders',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/profile_icon_fill.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/profile_icon.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: 'My Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontFamily: "AlbertSans"),
        unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontFamily: "AlbertSans"),
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
```

> **important points :**

```
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/race_icon_fill.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: appThemeColor,
            ),
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/race_icon.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: appLightGrayColor,
            ),
            label: 'My Races',
          ),

==========================================

            selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontFamily: AlbertSans),
            unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontFamily: AlbertSans, color: Colors.deepPurple),
```