# BottomNavigationBar // Cannot control item label color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

**Goal**: I want to give the item label a specific font and color depending on if it is selected or not.

**My approach**: As the label cannot be styled directly, I'm using the properties "unselectedLabelStyle" and "selectedLabelStyle".

**The Problem**:

- The properties work for font and fontweight, but I cannot directly control the text color
- I can influence the label color of the selected item; but not with the "selectedLabelStyle" property, but with the color I specifiy under "seltectedItemColor".
- "unselectedLabelStyle" also works for font and fontweight, but not for the color. I cannot find a property, that would allow me to change the color. > **THIS IS THE PROBLEM**

**Pretty picture (code below):**

[image]

**The code:**

```
BottomNavigationBar(
      elevation: 0,
      onTap: (index) => selectPage(index),
      currentIndex: selectedPageIndex,
      selectedItemColor:
          Provider.of<CustomColors>(context).customColorScheme['Dark Teal'],
      unselectedLabelStyle:
          Provider.of<CustomTextStyle>(context, listen: false)
              .customTextStyle('IconLabel'),
      selectedLabelStyle:
          Provider.of<CustomTextStyle>(context, listen: false)
              .customTextStyle('IconLabel'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: [
        //home
        bottomNavIcon(
          context: context,
          icon: Image.asset(
            "assets/icons/icon_home.png",
          ),
          icon_active: Image.asset("assets/icons/icon_home.png",
              color: Provider.of<CustomColors>(context)
                  .customColorScheme['Dark Teal']),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        //favorite
        bottomNavIcon(
          context: context,
          icon: Image.asset("assets/icons/icon_favorite.png"),
          icon_active: Image.asset("assets/icons/icon_favorite.png",
              color: Provider.of<CustomColors>(context)
                  .customColorScheme['Dark Teal']),
          label: 'Favorite',
        ),
        //loockback
        bottomNavIcon(
          context: context,
          icon: Image.asset("assets/icons/icon_lookback.png"),
          icon_active: Image.asset("assets/icons/icon_lookback.png",
              color: Provider.of<CustomColors>(context)
                  .customColorScheme['Dark Teal']),
          label: 'Lookback',
        ),
        //info & support
        bottomNavIcon(
          context: context,
          icon: Image.asset("assets/icons/icon_info.png"),
          icon_active: Image.asset("assets/icons/icon_info.png",
              color: Provider.of<CustomColors>(context)
                  .customColorScheme['Dark Teal']),
          label: 'Info & Support',
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Code for the icons

```
BottomNavigationBarItem bottomNavIcon(
{required BuildContext context,
required Image icon,
required Image icon_active,
required String label}) {


return BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.h, bottom: 3.h),
      child: icon,
    ),
    activeIcon: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.h, bottom: 3.h),
      child: icon_active,
    ),
    label: label,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the unselected items to have a certain color, use:

```
unselectedItemColor: Colors.red,
```

This will change the color of *label and icon both* for unselected items.

Example:

[image]

Unfortunately, `unselectedLabelStyle` property works for changing font weight, font size etc but not for color.

Also check this answer for [unselectedLabelstyle don't work in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61554581/12302691)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I swear I read through the mouseover for the BottomNavigationBar like 5 times and alwys missed that property.

Answer (score 0):

As the docmumentation say's, you can change the text color using the `color` property of `TextStyle` : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html

Once this say's perharps `BottomNavigationBar` overide the color when setting `selectedItemColor` and/or `unselectedItemColor`

After giving a try, effectively color is overide even if you don't provide `selectedItemColor` and/or `unselectedItemColor`